# php refresh every x amount of time on server side

Tags: php, lamp

I was wondering how can i call the same file every x amount of time.I am used to ajax, but this is only for when a website has users, i am not expecting any users i am just trying to make some operations on some files every x amount of time, lets say every 20 minutes. thank you. Does anyone know of some methods that can help me with this?

Comment: Use cron job for this purpose

Comment: no but looking at this link it seems a little too much work for what i am trying to do http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/

Comment: you can't do that in client side, the only option for you is to use cron jobs, if you want to run your page at specified time interval in your scenario

Comment: all you have to do is log into your server control panel, look for cron jobs, specify the page you want to execute and specify the time how often you want server to automatically run that page

Answer (score 3):

You need to do it on server side. Did you try cron jobs?

Comment: no thank you. can you please provide more info like links.so that i can vote up or accept. =) Also is there something simpler than this? it seem a little complicated.

Comment: Give more details about your server side env. Like OS, php versions and other softwares installed.

Comment: its linux lamp, its hosted in hostgator

Comment: Heres a link to cron tutorial. http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html

Answer (score 1):

This might help you, the link explains how to setup cron job in hostagator. The video in the link is well enough for you to go I guess

http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/how-do-i-create-and-delete-a-cron-job

Answer (score 1):

Type this at the command line on your linux server:

```
crontab -e
```

add this to the file and save:

```
20 * * * * curl -s http://example.com
```

this will fetch that url every 20 minutes, the -s option to curl just silences any output.